# Xamarin - PostAsync dont dosen't POST?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make an Android app that logs into a website and grabs the userpage that its redirects to after login, but I can't get it to work. If I run the code on a WinForm it works fine, but in Xamarin it doesn't log in and the page it returns the login page.

EDIT: Looks like the POST does work, if I enter the wrong password it returns the frontpage, and with the right password it returns the login page (And on PC I get the userpage which it redirects to after login)

*Why does this code work in Winform but not Xamarin, and how do i fix it?*

```
    private async Task<string> GetPage()
{
    var page = "";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", "login@email.com"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "mypassword")
    });
    var result = await client.PostAsync("https://www.notMySite.com/users/login", content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        page = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return page;
}
```

Comment: We need some more details here. What are you expecting to see? Does the page returned perhaps contain an error message telling you what went wrong? Have you checked that the headers sent are the same - especially the user-agent?

Comment: This is my first time working with anything like this. But i did fool around a bit and found out that on the winform i get a header with the key "Set-Cookie" with the value(s): "hasLogin=1" and "cookieSafe=Q2FrZQ%3D%3D.Z............" in Xamarin the "hasLogin" is missing.. Im guessing this might be my problem? How do i add that value tho?

Comment: if the server is setting that header key in the response for one request but not the other, you need to examine the two requests and compare them.  It might be that the user-agent is different between them and that affects how the server responds.

Comment: Also No, the pages dosen't show any errors. I expect it to redirect from the login page to the user page (and it does on PC with winforms) but insted it stays on the login page

Comment: Both headers  appears to be empty. I tried setting both user-agents to "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705" and the results are the same, works on PC, not on mobile (Android)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my problem is that it dident follow the redirect on Android. `

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

fixed my problem.